# Add script to ASP compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a login form using ASP .Net and i want put another variable data into DB but source code has compiled to dll files so i write a small script

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.ascx.cs" Inherits="Login.Web" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.Common"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>

<script runat="server">
    protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Database=Test;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Information(Info1,Info2) values(@Info1,@Info2)",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info1", Info1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info2", Info2.Text);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

</script>
```

into the Login.aspx file. When I run, "Info1" and "Info2" sent success to DB but Login Event didn't work
What did i wrong.
Note: Login.ascx.cs has compiled to Login.dll and i can't modify it.

Comment: Side note, Some required reading: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) & [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: "When I run, "Info1" and "Info2" sent success to DB but Login Event didn't work." What mean "sent success" and what do you mean that login event didn't work. Button on click is not working? But how you then "sent sucess"?

Comment: i don't think it cause "AddWithValue" because when i delete SQL parameters, it still didn't login. But when i delete "object sender" and "EventArgs e", Login event success but my script Insert didn't work. @Larnu

Comment: You missed the point of those articles then, @ReHoPham . I never said it was the problem here, but it is a problem.

Comment: @Sergey As normally, when i login, i can see the SELECT query in SQL trace and alert "Login Sucess". But after i added my script, only one INSERT query in my script shown and i can't see SELECT query in Login event.
Button on click work.

Comment: @Larnu This is the first time i post on SOF ^^ and sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is btnLoginButton_Click is defined in two places, the first one is inside “Login.Web” and the second one in your aspx.

So  when you click btnLoginButton it just calls method which is in the aspx,. So it never reaches the event which is inside compiled assembly

So the solution would be change click event to call different click event where you can call base click event

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLoginButton " runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnLoginButton2_Click" />



 <script runat="server">
   protected void  btnLoginButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Database=Test;Integrated Security=True;");
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Information(Info1,Info2) values(@Info1,@Info2)",con);       
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Info1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Info1.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Info1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Info2.Text;
       int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       btnLoginButton_Click(sender, e);
   }
```